# Is there an easy way to join objects and create a new texture only showing the visible parts?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, uv

Today I faced the problem that Blender suddenly crashed every time I opened render view or started actually rendering. I knew that my scene could cause issues like that one day as I filled it up with many (free) objects which I found on several platforms - so neither the meshes nor the textures are optimized I think.

Okay, to keep things short: one part of the scene is a book shelf with many books on it. By now every book is an object on its own with it's own material with 3 PBR image maps showing the front and back side as well as the spine (I think this is the word for it - sorry, I am not a native English speaker). I have 30 or 40 books in the scene where you usually only see the spine (as the front and the back side are hidden by the books nearby, they stand in a row) so I wondered if there is a good way to a) join the books standing close to each other to get one object and b) generating one material with images which only include the visible parts. So in this way I may achieve to join 20 books in a row, reduce the faces by deleting the not visible part and somehow reduce the 20 materials each with 3 texture maps to one material with the "merged" 3 texture maps.

I hope it became clear... Basically the question is: how can I reduce textures / materials in a scene when I know that large parts of the textures are never seen?